# Avoiding Gradle dependencies download in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When I am building the Gradle file for the first time, it is downloading all the dependencies successfully. If I am trying to build consecutively, the dependencies taking from the downloaded cache.

When I am restarting the machine, the eclipse is again downloading the dependencies instead of taking from the cache instead of taking from the cache.

Is there any eclipse configuration to avoid the downloading process each time I restart the machine?

Comment: The first time you're building your gradle project, it will download all the dependent jars into your machine (probably to .gradle folder inside user folder). For every gradle build,it'll look for jars inside that folder before downloading, if something is missing, it'll download the missing dependency. The reason its downloading the dependent jars again after restart is due to unavailability of dependent jars in local. Probably ur user folder contents are resetted once u restart ur machine.Maybe u've a third party application (like DeepFreeze) which is resetting the contents for each restart.

Comment: As you said if the user folder is resetting, the jars which are downloaded for first time exists in gradle home right. Then how to avoid downloading every time restarting the machine.

Comment: Remove any third party applications which resets your user folder.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it by making the gradle build to build the application in offline mode, where it contacts the local gradle home for repeated build process.

Settings are,

Windows -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Arguments ->

Under Program Arguments, Use, enter the following command and rebuild.

--offline